# Помогите реализовать алгоритм на с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Алгоритм:(разбиваем строку на слова)

1. Запоминаешь позицию символа.
2. Идешь по каждому символу строки, пока не встретишь пробел, точку, запятую или какой другой символ разделитель - это будет конец слова.
3. Берешь подстроку от первой позиции (п.1) до полученной - это будет само слово.
4. Идешь дальше, пока символы-разделители не закончатся. Как закончатся - это начало следующего слова. Далее - п.1 и так до конца строки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {

        char *tempSlova = new char[20]; 
        char *myString = new char[100];
        cout << "Vvedite stroky ";
        gets(myString);

        cout << "Slova v stroke:" << endl;

        for(int i = 0, k =0 ; i <= strlen(myString); i++, k ++)
        {       
                if(myString[i] == ' '|| myString[i] == '\0')
                {       
                        tempSlova[k] = '\0';
                        if(tempSlova[0]=='\0')
                            tempSlova[0]=0;
                        printf("%s ", tempSlova);
                        k=-1;
                }
                else
                        tempSlova[k] = myString[i];

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Молодец, это шаг вперед. Теперь сделайте хотя бы одну попытку выразить это кодом.

Comment: @Igor Я уже не могу)))  мозг кипит)))

Comment: Я Вам начну:  `int main() { ...`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большое)) вы очень добрый)

Comment: я с++ в университете учил давно не практиковал но думаю функция strtok во вполне должна помочь в вашем алгоритме.

Comment: @Igor я правила, посмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: Даша, а вот это что и зачем? `if( tempSlova[0] == '\0' ) ...`. Потом, проверьте что будет, если в исходной строке встретится больше 1 пробела подряд. Или одно слово будет длинней 20 символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо так последовательно, как у вас описано, реализовать алгоритм.

Из вашего кода совершенно не понятно, на каком языке вы пишите программу: то ли на C, то ли на C++. С одной стороны, используются C++ стандартный поток вывода, с другой стороны функции C.

Для начала функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена в C++, как

```
int main()
```

Нет никакого смысла динамически распределять массивы. Их можно было объявить локальными переменными.

Функция `gets` является небезопасный, и уже даже не поддерживается самим стандартом языка C. Поэтому не следует ее пользоваться.

Если вам надо просто вывести на консоль слова из предложения, то нет необходимости объявлять вспомогательный массив.

Чтобы распознавать знаки пунктуации и пробелов, можно воспользоваться стандартными C функциями, объявленными в заголовке `<cctype>`. Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char s[N];

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";

    if ( std::cin.getline( s, sizeof( s ) ) )
    {
        for ( const char *p = s; *p;  )
        {
            while ( std::ispunct( ( unsigned char )*p ) || 
                    std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

            const char *first = p;

            while ( *p && !std::ispunct( ( unsigned char )*p ) &&
                          !std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

            if ( first != p ) std::cout.write( first, p - first ) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог работы с программой может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Enter a sentence: first, second, third, fourth, fifth!
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```